# How can I restrict users not to create new posts - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, hook, action

When someone click on **Add New** post then a message will appear like "you are not allowed to create posts" and users also not allow to publish or draft the post.

**I tried this code -:**

```
function post_published_limit( $ID, $post ) {
    $max_posts = 5; // change this or set it as an option that you can retrieve.
    $author = $post->post_author; // Post author ID.
    $count = count_user_posts( $author, 'post'); // get author post count

    if ( $count > $max_posts ) {
        // count too high, let's set it to draft.
        $post->post_status = 'draft';
        wp_update_post( $post);
    }
}
add_action( 'publish_post', 'post_published_limit', 10, 2 );
```

This code helps me not to publish the post but it creates draft of that posts .

Comment: And what exactly is your problem/question with this code?

Comment: I don't even want to make draft of a post.

Comment: Then don't include `wp_update_post( $post);`

Comment: `$post->post_status = 'draft';` is clearly where that happens. From what I understand, the `publish_post` hook is run when a post is actually submitted. You don't want to reject it when a user has already gone through the trouble of writing it. Rather, find an [action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) that executes when the user attempts to create a post.

Comment: @MarkusAO Correct

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean but I think this will do the trick.

```
function post_published_limit( $ID, $post ) {
    global $current_user; 
    get_currentuserinfo(); 

    if ( user_can( $current_user, "administrator" ) ){ 
      $max_posts = 5; 
      $author = $post->post_author; // Post author ID.
      $count = count_user_posts( $author, 'post'); 

      if ( $count > $max_posts ) {
          $post->post_status = 'draft';
          wp_update_post( $post);
      }
   }
}
```